# Error bundling Meteor application?

Tags: meteor

When I try and bundle my Meteor application I get:

```
$ meteor bundle app.tgz
Errors prevented bundling:
Exception while bundling application:
Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (/usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse-js.js:263:18)
    at js_error (/usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse-js.js:271:11)
    at croak (/usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse-js.js:733:9)
    at token_error (/usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse-js.js:740:9)
    at unexpected (/usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse-js.js:746:9)
    at /usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse-js.js:1124:9
    at maybe_unary (/usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse-js.js:1209:19)
    at expr_ops (/usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse-js.js:1236:24)
    at maybe_conditional (/usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse-js.js:1240:20)
    at maybe_assign (/usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse-js.js:1264:20)
```

The application works fine locally, and I can't understand what is wrong from the error message. Not even sure which file to start looking for the problem in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor is trying to minify your javascript and the internal parser used by uglifyjs is encountering an error. Are you sure your javascript is free of syntax errors? Are the semi-colons all in the right places? Do you get any console errors in the browser?

Also, please specify which version of Meteor you're using.

Comment: Thanks there was a Javascript syntax error when I look in the JS console.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't currently have any directories, that you don't want to include, inside your project's dir, like for example a previous bundle/ directory. This will definitely cause the JS_Parse_error when bundling, but will not prevent you from running your app through meteor run or mrt - Such a simple mistake, but might cost you precious hours to figure out.

Comment: Kind an abstractish answer. Any auto-magic possible? Detecting such a mistake?